# ¿Cómo elimino las vocales de una cadena?

Tags: python, string

Quiero hacer una funcion que devuelva el texto que haya ingresado el usuario pero sin ninguna vocal, no importa si fue escrita con mayusculas o minusculas.

Luego como extra, me gustaria invertirlo pero eso creo que es mas facil.

Este es mi código:

```
def invertirSinVocales():
    vocales = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O","U")
    texto = (input("ingrese un texto: "))
    while vocales in texto:
        texto2= texto.replace(vocales,"")
        return texto2

print(invertirSinVocales())
```

El problema esta que me dice que espera que "vocales" sea un str y es una tupla en realidad.

Comment: Como nota al margen, nótese que Python recomienda usar `funciones_con_nombre_asi` y no `funcionesConNombreAsi`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hola prueba esto a ver si es lo que necesitas:

```
texto = ("introduzca el texto").lower()

vocales = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')

for letra in vocales:
    texto = texto.replace(letra, "")

#Invierte la cadena
texto = texto[::-1]
print (texto)
```

Comment: bueniiismo gracias, solo tuve que agregar un "input" para que introduzca el texto, pero aparte de eso me soluciono el problema. Estaba formulando mal el for y habia metido un while que no iba. Gracias!

Comment: Personalmente quitaría `vocales` y dejaría el for solo como `for letra in 'aeiou': texto = texto.replace(letra, "")`

Answer (score 11):

Un par de opciones más "rebuscadas":

- Usar `str.traslate`:

  ```
  cad = "camión cigüeña Avión"
  trans_table = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys('aeiouAEIOUüáéíóúÜÁÉÍÓÚ'))
  res = cad.translate(trans_table)
  print(res) # cmn cgñ vn
  ```

  `str.maketrans` permite crear una tabla que será usada para substituir cada carácter por el que le corresponda. Recibe un diccionario dónde las parejas `clave: valor` son:

  ```
  caracter_a_substituir: carácter que lo substituye
  ```

  como en este caso queremos eliminarlos basta con que sea de la forma:

  ```
  {"a": None, "b": None, ...}
  ```

  que es lo que crea `dict.fromkeys('aeiouAEIOUüáéíóúÜÁÉÍÓÚ')`. Por su lado `str.maketrans` retorna un diccionario similar pero convirtiendo las claves en valores numéricos (codepoints unicode de cada carácter).

  `str.translate` se limita a recorrer la cadena y usar la tabla para cambiar cada carácter por el que le pertenece, retornando la nueva cadena al terminar.
- Usando expresiones regulares con `re.sub`:`

  ```
  import re

  cad = "camión cigüeña Avión"
  res = re.sub(r'[AEIOUÜÁÉÍÓÚ]', '', cad, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
  print(res) # cmn cgñ vn
  ```

  Esto no requiere mucha explicación, busca en la cadena cada coincidencia con el patrón y la substituye por el segundo argumento (una cadena vacía en este caso). La bandera `re.IGNORECASE` hace que no diferencie entre mayúsculas y minúsculas al buscar las coincidencias con el patrón.

Comment: Gran aporte @FJSevilla!

Answer (score 7):

puedes usar "List comprehensions" así (actualizada con las sugerencias de @FJsevilla):

```
vocales = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O","U"}
texto = "asdqwezclkjoiuhgf"
texto_sin_vocales = "".join(nv for nv in texto if nv not in vocales)
#'sdqwzclkjhgf'
```

Espero te sirva y cualquier duda puedes comentarla.

---

Explicacion en Español:

- `"".join()`: Unir los elementos de la lista separandolos con el caracter `""`
- `[nv for nv in texto if nv not in vocales]`: añadir a la lista cada caracter (`nv`) en el string `texto` si `nv` no se encuentra en la lista `vocales`.

Esto, escrito como un `for` tradicional sería:

```
    lista = [] 
    for nv in texto:
        if nv not in vocales:
            lista.append(nv)
    texto_sin_vocales = "".join(lista)
```

Comment: lo pude solucionar con el comentario de arriba, me pareció mas fácil de entender, aunque creo que tu código funciona, le doy manito arriba :)

Comment: Gracias, voy a editarla para expliar un poco, no para que cambies la respuesta aceptada sino para que los prôximos que la lean la puedan encontrar mas detallada :)

Comment: Esta es una buena respuesta a la vez que simple. Mucho más eficiente que `str.replace` que crea una nueva cadena cada vez que se llama. Si quieres mejorar aún más la eficiencia usa un conjunto `vocales = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O","U"}` y no una lista para las vocales (la búsqueda en tablas hash es mucho más eficiente que en un array/lista) y usa un generador por compresión y no una lista (que no se va a usar para nada y ocupa memoria innecesaria) `"".join(nv for nv in texto if nv not in vocales)`. Un saludo.

Comment: @FJSevilla Gracias por la sugerencia. Actualizado.

Answer (score 5):

Saludos puedes hacer algo asi:

```
def removerVocales(palabra):
  letras = []
  for caracter in palabra:
    if caracter.lower() not in 'aeiou':
      letras.append(caracter)
  return ''.join(letras) 

print (removerVocales('Diego'))
```

Resultado:

[image: result]

**Explicación:**
La función **removerVocales** recibe como parametro una **palabra** , despues mediante un ciclo **for** recorremos dicha palabra y mediante un condicional **if** verificamos si existe alguna vocal previa conversion a minuscula(.lower).

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Answer (score 0):

```
palabrasinVocal=""
userWord=str(input("Ingrese una palabra: "))
userWord=userWord.upper()


for letra in userWord:
    if letra=='A':
        continue 
    elif letra=='E':
        continue
    elif letra=='I':
        continue
    elif letra=='O':
        continue
    elif letra=='U':
        continue
    palabrasinVocal+=letra
print(palabrasinVocal)
```

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a StackOverflow en español. Puedes agregar una explicación de las razones por la que el código de la pregunta falla y cómo lo resuelve tu respuesta por favor (no soy experto en python pero me parece que tu código no lo resuelve). Recomiendo leer [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del sitio y ganes tu primera medalla.

Answer (score -1):

Esta es una manera muy sencilla:

```
vocales=["a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U"] #declaración de vocales a remover
print("¡Devorador de vocales!") #nombre del programa
userWord = str(input("Ingresa una palabra: ")) #ingreso de la palabra por el usuario
#en este ciclo se irá imprimiendo la letra que no esté en las vocales declaradas
for letra in userWord: 
    if letra not in vocales:
        print(letra)
```

Comment: Considera añadir una explicación del funcionamiento del método que empleas. Además haces la conversión a mayúsculas para que funcione tu código, pero dejas la solución así, y no se pide. Deberías de volver a dejar el texto como se ingresó por teclado o bien agregar todas las posibilidades a vocales.

Comment: podrías colocar el parámetro `end=""` en el `print()` para dar un poco más de realismo, de lo contrario tendrías que reemplazar los caracteres con el método `replace`

Answer (score -2):

```
#Eliminar vocales de una palabra
palabra = input("Escriba aqui una palabra: ")

for letra in palabra:
    if letra == "a":
        continue
    if letra == "e":
        continue
    if letra == "i":
        continue
    if letra == "o":
        continue
    if letra == "u":
        continue
    print("Sin vocales: ", letra)
```